# How to upload big size file without changing memory_limit size?

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

I am trying to upload file through ftp code but issue is that I am not able to upload more than `50MB` file through the following code. 
`memory_limit is 64M`, that is why I am trying to do it through ftp code. Any solution how to upload big size file without changing the `memory_limit`??

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $title          =   sql_replace($_POST['title']);
        $desc           =   sql_replace($_POST['desc']);

        if(!$title)
        { $errors .= "File Title is Missing !<br>"; }

        if(!$desc)
        { $errors .= "Description is Missing !<br>"; }

        if(!$errors){

        /************UPLOAD WITH FTP***********/


        // set up basic connection
        $ftp_server     =   'IP here...';
        $ftp_user_name  =   '.....';
        $ftp_user_pass  =   '*******';


        $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

        // login with username and password
        $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

        // upload a file

        $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

                if (ftp_put($conn_id, $file, $tmp, FTP_ASCII)) {
                 echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
                } else {
                 echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
                 $errors .=  "Invalid file<br>";
                }
                // close the connection
                ftp_close($conn_id);

        }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `memory-limit` parameter has very little to do with file uploads.

Check your php.ini file for this parameter `upload_max_filesize = 50M`

You will have to increase this limit, try `upload_max_filesize = 60M` as there will always be some other stuff in the payload above and beyond your actual file.

ALTERNATIVE SUGGESTION:

Yes I believe you can set this using the ini_set() function so you could do it from code like this:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '60M');
```

Comment: But is there any other solution without changing the upload_max_filesize??